# TextView and Button in ListView - OnClick works, OnItemClick does not work

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick, onitemclick

**UPDATE**

My button is as big as the view of each ListItem - maybe this causes the problem? Is it possible to press once and let both OnItemclick and OnClick respond?

---

I have a list view with two textviews and a button. I know there are a lot of questions being posted but I have read a lot of them and not one seems to work.

I want the OnItemClick of each view of the list view to work.
I also want the OnClick of the button inside each view of the list view to work.

Only the onClick of the button seems to respond

In my xml i have set `android:focusable="false"` for the button. For the textviews I have set `android:textIsSelectable="false" android:clickable="false" android:focusable="false"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_order"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/order_height"
    >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/timer_size"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the layout for my list view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/order_height"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the GetView of my adapter i have :

```
 Button b = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pending);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(numberOfTimers < 2){
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.ongoing);
                countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(TIME_PANINI, 1000,timerTextView, view);
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

in my main activity i have a onItemClickListener set to the listView:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.d(TAG_MAIN, "we are in select onitemclicklistener");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BOOOOH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you try android:duplicateParentState="true" for textview?

Comment: Yes, tried this and the OnItemClickListener still doesn't respond.

Comment: Make ListView focusable

Comment: Have set android:focusable="true" but no response from onItemclickListener. I have Updated my question, please look at the top, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace OnClickListener with OnTouchListener.

Like this:

```
b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            if(numberOfTimers < 2){
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.ongoing);
                countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(TIME_PANINI, 1000,timerTextView, view);
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};);
```

When you return false at this listener, you mean "hey i'm not done with that action(press down), please let the action to the next View"

Comment: Thanks. Implemented this, but the button keeps blocking the action from going to the view of the list view.